# Capitalize a single 'char'acter in C#?

Tags: c#, char, capitalize

Is there a "simple" way to capitalize a single `char`-typed value?

This will work, but feels cumbersome and generally wrong:

```
var ch = 'a';
var cap = ("" + ch).ToUpper()[0];
cap.Dump(); // (in LINQPad) => 'A'
```

Notes:

1. The choice of `"" + ch` over `ToString()` is because ReSharper yells at me for not specifying a culture with the latter ... in any case, `ch.ToString().ToUpper()[0]` feels just as cumbersome.
2. For the sake of globalization, *just "adding 32" is not an option*; I do not believe there is any single `char` that turns into a surrogate-pair when capitalized.

Thanks,

Comment: "Adding 26" isn't even an option in ASCII: You'd need to subtract 32 instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Char.ToUpper(ch)
```

should do the job.

Comment: Brilliant. I was looking only at the [intellisense] instance methods... should have RTFM'ed.

Comment: I fall into the same trap sometimes.  It's usually worth looking at static methods on familiar types just to see what's available.  In this case I searched in Reflector for ToUpper methods to see how they work internally, but instead found this method.

Answer (score 2):

try `Char.ToUpper()`

```
var a = 'a';
a = Char.ToUpper(a);
```